# Autodesk forge Viewer in React Application markup extension`s not all functions don`t come

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a React Apllication and integrated Autodesk forge viewer. I have a markup extension for viewer and its work correctly without React. When i try to add extension to React viewer, extensions functions are loaded not fully (all functions beside onToolbarCreated).
I need to know where i must  include  extensions javascript file and why onToolbarcreated function is not loaded?

i got this error in console`

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cerDR.png)

[Extension code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSRNR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check here:

- `onToolbarCreated` is only effective when using Viewer v7 or later
- it'd only get called after the `Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT` event is fired
- you can either add a breakpoint inside your function or print to the console in there to detect if and when it's called instead of printing it to the console in your load callback ...

Comment: Thank you, you are right i tried to run extension on Viewer v6